# Cpanel/WHM not working

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty, cpanel

Everything work fine, suddenly today afternoon Both cpanel and WHM stop working.

But still the website and SSH work fine, But i am unable to open cpanel or whm, when i opening using IP

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2082
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2083
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2087
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.:2086
```

[image]

It showing **Unable to connect.**

> I tried with all browser, different IP, By reboot, restarting server
>   but it the error remain same.

Even i am unable to contact support.cpanel.net because it need cpanel support access number which i is inside the whm and whm is not opening.

Please give me the solutions to fix.

Thanks you.

Comment: Your image link does not work.,  upload to `i.stack.imgur.com`, to ensure people access it.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated.

Comment: The error indicates you have nothing configure at that address on that port.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Problem for user too many ways, and some are about computer software (firewall)

Answer (score 1):

There're different possibilities.

1. First, check that you local computer, has open port for out 2087, 2086, 2082, 2083.
2. Second, check same (incomming) on remote server. On shell for every port that you need check:

try

```
root@host [~]#iptables -L -n |grep 2087
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:2087
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:2087
```

3. If not closed, try `telnet IP_SERVER port`
4. if not get response, check if Cpanel service it's active

try

```
 root@host [~]#service cpanel status
 cpsrvd (pid  10600) is running...
```

5. if not running try `service cpanel start`
6. if not start, you are a problem with cpanel install